# Encoding error using csv.reader on io file object with non-ascii encoding

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, encoding

I am trying to read a csv file with cp1252 encoding like this:

```
import io
import csv

csvr = csv.reader(io.open('data.csv', encoding='cp1252'))

for row in csvr:
    print row
```

The relevant content of 'data.csv' is

```
Curva IV
Fecha: 27-Jul-2016 16:22:40
Muestra: 1
Tensión      Corriente      Ig
0.000000e+000   1.154330e-004   -2.984730e-004
...
```

and I get the following output

```
['Curva IV']
['Fecha: 27-Jul-2016 16:22:40']
['Muestra: 1']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/sandbox/bla.py", line 347, in <module>
    mist()
  File "D:/sandbox/bla.py", line 343, in mist
    for row in csvr:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf3' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

which I do not understand at all. Obviously the critical line is that with the accent on the 'o'. It seems like the iterator of the object returned by csv.reader is attempting to do a conversion. The exception is raised before the print statement, so it is not a problem with my terminal encoding. Any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> Note
>
> This version of the csv module doesn’t support Unicode input. Also,
>   there are currently some issues regarding ASCII NUL characters.
>   Accordingly, all input should be UTF-8 or printable ASCII to be safe;
>   see the examples in section Examples.

The input has to be converted to UTF-8 before passing it to csv.reader.